# Why Zipalign cannot work properly with .pvr files?

Tags: compression, apk, zipalign

I am using .pvr files in my Android game. But when compressing it using Zipalign, the size of .pvr files are no change (another type of file worked well)

I tried to use the newest Zipalign tool, change flags

tools/windows/zipalign -v -f 4 C:_Working\Game.apk release_apk\Game.apk

Answer (score 0):

The `zipalign` tool is not about compressing but about "aligning" elements in the zip file, which means moving them at a position in the zip file which is a multiple of bytes of the value you give (in this case 4 -- which means, every uncompressed element is located at an offset multiple of 4). Compression is completely orthogonal to zip-aligning.

Depending on what tool you use to build your APK, some build systems may keep some files uncompressed, so you should look at the documentation.

Another possibility is that the `.pvr` file is already compressed in itself so zipping it brings little gain in size.